# I need a fixed-size icon that doesn't scale for zoom in/zoom out [MapBox]

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

For example, if you imagine a map with a vehicle icon on it, when you zoom out, you probably don't want a vehicle that expands to the size of a city, you'd like to keep something that continues to occupy the same amount of space on the road.

See this example:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UC4lsJa7_Xct7-bWuU0fRwH0eyqf1EUe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: if it's svg icon, you just put width and height  in pixels in the svg

Comment: This method does not work, I want the size to be fixed so that the size of the icon becomes small when I zoom out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression in the style layer definition, which might look something like this:

```
{
    id: "locations",
    type: "symbol",
    layout: {
        "icon-image": "information",
        "icon-allow-overlap": true,
        "icon-size": [
            'interpolate',
            // Set the exponential rate of change to 1.5
            ['exponential', 1.5],
            ['zoom'],
            // When zoom is 10, icon will be 50% size.
            10,
            0.5,
            // When zoom is 22, icon will be 10% size.
            22,
            0.1
        ],
    }
};
```

Basically the *icon-size* portion is what you're going to want to be adding. You can read a little more about [icon-size](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#layout-symbol-icon-size) here in the docs.

Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/joshkautz/pen/OJwWKKr). *Replace <<<YOUR_TOKEN>>> with your API Token.*

Comment: Additionally, here is a link to the Mapbox documentation about interpolation, which may be useful for you: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#interpolate

Comment: This method changes the size of the icon based on the height, but I want the size of the icon to get smaller as it goes up [Zoom out]

Comment: As it happens in reality, the higher you go, the smaller the size of the car, I want the same for maps

Comment: See this example:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UC4lsJa7_Xct7-bWuU0fRwH0eyqf1EUe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The example I shared has the icon size grow smaller when the zoom decreases (zooms out), and has the icon size grow larger when the zoom increases (zooms in). Do you have a CodeSandbox demo you can share?

Comment: Part of what I want has succeeded, through your example, but I want the size to get smaller based on the size of the icon itself, meaning when zoom out the size of the icon gets smaller based on its basic size, so if the icon is a building or a car, their size will be different

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to mess around with the expression. See the link to the docs I posted in the comment. Without a working example nobody will be able to tell you exact numbers to plug in for it to look exactly how you want. You're going to have to try testing the different types of interpolation (linear, exponential, cubic-bezier) to see what works best for your map.